# Multiple requests when signing up with file on parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to build an android application using parse to store user data.
In the user table, I am storing username password, status, and a profile picture.

I am trying to create a signup page, and to do that I am using `file.saveInBackground` to upload the image file and then `user.signUpInBackground` to sign up the user.
It is working fine, but every time a user sign's up it makes multiple requests (around 30).
Is there any particular reason why this is happening?

```java
private void addUser(String username, String role, String password) {

        final ParseFile file = new ParseFile(photoFile);

        file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setUsername(username);
                    user.setRole(role);
                    user.setPassword(password);
                    user.setProfileImage(file);
                    user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error while signing up!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            goMainActivity();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: How do you see these multiple requests?

Comment: In plan usage on back4app Dashboard

Comment: This specific operation should perform only two requests, but note that reloading the dashboard and also other operations on the app can be making the additional requests.